# REGEX Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby, regex

I have:

```
string = "4/28 - Declined 4/19 - Call with Bob, Joe and Steve 4/10 - Call scheduled for 10a on 4/18 4/9 - Wants to meet with Jay on 4/28 at 10:30a"
```

I am trying to produce an array that gives an array of four elements:

```
4/28 - Declined
4/19 - Call with Bob, Joe and Steve
4/10 - Call scheduled for 10a on 4/18
4/9 - Wants to meet with Jay on 4/28 at 10:30a
```

I'm having trouble with the following:

```
string.scan(/\d{1,2}+\/\d{1,2}[\s]?[-|:]+\s[A-Za-z\s\d]+ (?![\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}]* -)/)
```

I get:

```
["4/19 - Call with ", "4/10 - Call scheduled for 10a on ", "4/9 - Wants to meet with Jay on "]
```

Comment: This `(?! [\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}]* [ ] - )` is problematic. What is that intended to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regexp:

```
(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}.+?(?:(?=\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} - )|\z))
```

Check the result here http://rubular.com/r/04VL4Qs7Kb

It returns this matches:

```
Match 1
1.  4/28 - Declined
Match 2
1.  4/19 - Call with Bob, Joe and Steve
Match 3
1.  4/10 - Call scheduled for 10a on 4/18
Match 4
1.  4/9 - Wants to meet with Jay on 4/28 at 10:30a
```

The important parts:

it starts with a "date" and then anything else (note the last `?`, it makes the `.+` or `.*` be "non-greedy")

```
\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}.+?
```

up until the next "date followed by a dash" OR the end of the line (this OR is important, or you won't get the last match)

```
(?=\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} - )|\z)
```

that `?:` is there to ignore the group on the result

```
(?:(...))
```

otherwise you get a blank second group on each match

```
Match 1
1.  4/28 - Declined
2.   
Match 2
1.  4/19 - Call with Bob, Joe and Steve
2.   
Match 3
1.  4/10 - Call scheduled for 10a on 4/18
2.   
Match 4
1.  4/9 - Wants to meet with Jay on 4/28 at 10:30a
2.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string.split(%r{(\d+/\d+ - )}).drop(1).each_slice(2).map(&:join)
```

Output:

```
[
  "4/28 - Declined ",
  "4/19 - Call with Bob, Joe and Steve ",
  "4/10 - Call scheduled for 10a on 4/18 ",
  "4/9 - Wants to meet with Jay on 4/28 at 10:30a"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the *natural separator* is this `\d{1,2}+ / \d{1,2} \s? [-:]+`

So you can use that in a negative assertion to get the body of the message.

`\d{1,2}+/\d{1,2}\s?[-:]+(?:(?!\d{1,2}+/\d{1,2}\s?[-:]+)[\S\s])*`

https://regex101.com/r/o8Grdx/1

Formatted

```
 \d{1,2}+ / \d{1,2} \s? [-:]+ 
 (?:
      (?! \d{1,2}+ / \d{1,2} \s? [-:]+ )
      [\S\s] 
 )*
```